# Cannot read property 'executeScript'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

New to this, thanks for any help.

This works well when invoked by the popup.html -> popup.js. But when I set the manifest.json to execute via a content_scripts, returns error Cannot read property 'executeScript'

```
manifest.json:
...
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://www.google.com/*"],
    "js": ["jQuery Core 3.4.1.js", "content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }],

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
...

    content.js:

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) 
    {
            if (request.action === "getSource") 
            {
                message.innerText = request.source;
            }
    });

    function onWindowLoad() {
    var message = document.querySelector('#message');

        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            file: "getPagesSource.js"
        },
            function () 
            {
                if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                    message.innerText = "There was an error injecting script : \n" + chrome.runtime.lastError.message;
                }
            });
        }

    window.onload = onWindowLoad;
```

Comment: 1) Content scripts can't use chrome.tabs API, 2) you don't need executeScript for getPageSource.js because your content script already runs in the page and has direct access to its DOM, 3) See the [overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) for more info on the various extension contexts.

Comment: very good.. Thank you